# How do i access search from controller for input type=Search in mvc4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

How do i access search from controller for input type=Search in mvc4.
here is my view cshtml code.

My code:

```
<input name="searchValue" id="searchinput1" type="search" data-mini="true" data-align="left"/>
```

I have a buttton inbuilt in my search and wanted to access in controller. Tried possibilities over internet, but couldnt find a better solution.
I dont want to have button and text box individually, rather have this type=search itself.

[image: Search image]

i want the search functionality to be implemented by clicking the button on left side of search within the search box.

Comment: one more thing to be seen is this search is in layout page. want this to be accessed in layout page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in your view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
           {@Html.TextBox("name", null, new { id = "SearchBox", @class = "SearchBox" })}
```

In your controller add the following code

```
public ActionResult Search(string name)
    {
        //do anything with the name
}
```

you will be able to access your text box in controller

Answer (score 1):

`type="search"` can't automatically bind to your action. It is almost like a normal textbox `<input type="text">`, but browser(chrome and safari for now) might tweak it slightly to make it cuter. You have to manually hook up events(onkeydown() may be) if don't want button beside.

Comment: i am using this for mobile view

Comment: Its up to your design strategy(css stuffs) whatever look and feel you want. But you have inject your action binding logic on that button, there are no automatic things going to happen.